# Can I generate a 'templateUrl' value for every single product on json dynamically as I created the view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm creating an web app using JavaScript framework i.e. AngularJS.

The App is a store which takes product info from JSON and displays it on  elements.

My question: Can I generate a 'templateUrl' value for every single product on JSON dynamically as I created the view?

```
var app = angular.module("oldek_clothes", ["ngRoute"]);
        var A = "i'm 'a'";
        var B = "i'm 'b'";
        var C = "i'm 'c'";
        var D = "views/store.html";

        app.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when("/A",{
                templateUrl : "views/store.html"
            })
            .when("/B", {
                template: B
            })
            .when("/C", {
                template: C
            })
            .when("/store",{
                templateUrl: D
            })
        });
```

The goal is create an single URL for each item stored in the JSON data, without excessive manual coding.

Answer (score 2):

If products are fixed you can create hash map for products as keys and route conf as value, suppose if products json is prod_json

```
   if prod_json = {"prod_a": val1, "prod_b": val2, "prod_c": val3}
   var routeConfig = {
    "prod_a":{
        route: "/A",
        templateUrl: "/sample/A.html"
    },
    "prod_b":{
        route: "/B",
        template: "<p>Sample paragraph B</p>"
    },
    "prod_c":{
        route: "/c",
        templateUrl: "/sample/c.html"
    },
    "prod_d":{
        route: "/D",
        template: "<p>Sample paragraph B</p>"
    }]
   app.config(function($routeProvider) {
     for ( let prod in prod_json) {
       let conf = routeConfig[prod]
       $routeProvider.when(conf.route, conf.template?{template: conf.template}:{templateUrl: conf.templateUrl})
     }
   })
```

Comment: Can you explain me the function of the iteration?

Comment: iteration is just for looping through the routeConf and define app routes based on the products json we have. There is no difference between the defining routes using loop that i have mentioned and routes the way you have defined. check this link once https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js